# if stop within function not detecting column

Tags: r

I have written a function that should stop if a certain column is not recognised as a date format, I have implemented this like:

```
if(is.Date(dataname[,datename]) !=TRUE) { stop("Please format the date column as a date column")}
```

However within the function this is giving me an error :

```
func1 <-function(dataname,datename){ ... }

func1(dataname,"date")


 Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

Meaning the date column isn't detected.

However when I try this outside of a function it works perfectly:

```
 if(is.Date(dataname[,"date"]) !=TRUE) { print("Please format the date column as a date column")}
 if(is.Date(dataname[,"date"]) !=FALSE) { print("Please format the date column as a date column")}
 "Please format the date column as a date column"
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: I guess that the problem arises since `data` is also the name of a `base` R function and that function is passed as argument to `func1` instead of a `data.frame`. Hard to say without knowing your function and the argument you are passing.

Comment: @nicola I've isolated the problem to that line, I don't think the rest of the function is relevant.

Comment: In you first line, you wrote `dataname[,date]`. In the others, `dataname[,"date"]`. The error is due to what @nicola pointed out. Voting to close.

Comment: Could you possibly have forgotten the quotes around `date` in your first code sample? Later on you use `"date"`.

Comment: So you know what is relevant and what not. Why didn't you already find where the error comes from?

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to get lost with the edits. Function arguments change name and the body of the function is not provided (except for a single line that might or might not be correct, depending on what is written before in the function).

Comment: `is.Date()`  already returns logical value, no need to compare `!=`.

Comment: @Pascal the first line is within the function so "date" is supplied, the last lot of lines are outside of a function

Comment: @nicola The error is coming from the first line of code in my post, but I don't know why.

Comment: Stop to edit your post as it is confusing everybody. Please post the **whole** function and a **minimal reproducible** example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
func1 <- function(df, col){

  if( !is(df[, col], "Date") ){
    stop("Please format the date column as a date column") 
  } else {
    "all good"  
  }
}

#dummy data
data <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2010-12-31", "2010-11-01")),
                   x = 1:2)

#testing
func1(data, "date")
# [1] "all good"

func1(data, "x")
# Error in func1(data, "x") : 
#   Please format the date column as a date column
```

Comment: This attempt has solved my problem, but can you offer any explanation on why?

Comment: @user1987097 First provide your function in full in your post, with example data. Then we can try to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I'm unable to provide the function. Can you please advise me on what could be the culprit if this is the solution?

Comment: @user1987097 we do not need the full function, just provide us the line where you are doing the test if the column is a date, something similar to my post. Dummy data and a minimal function.

Comment: That's the first line of code in my question.